# how can I access to something in api to my app.js file?

Tags: javascript, node.js, api

In this [api](https://api.darksky.net/forecast/a6e1a451373ac75d8c4ef09f5b06892e/37.8267,-122.4233) I want to access to icon file from forecast.js file in to app.js file. But I can't do it. Because I want to show icons in html file

Api Response:

```
{
   (...)
   "daily":{
      "summary":"No precipitation throughout the week, with high temperatures falling to 64°F on Sunday.",
      "icon":"clear-day",
      "data":[
         {
            "time":1565766000,
            "summary":"Partly cloudy throughout the day.",
            "icon":"clear-day",
            (...)
            "precipProbability":0.02,
            (...)
            "temperatureMin":62.97,
            "temperatureMinTime":1565794800,
            "temperatureMax":77.39,
            "temperatureMaxTime":1565823600,
            (...)
         },
         (...)
      ]
   },
   (...)
}
```

from forecast.js files code

```
const request = require('request');

const forecast = (latitude, longitude, callback) => {
    const url = 'https://api.darksky.net/forecast/a6e1a451373ac75d8c4ef09f5b06892e/' + latitude + ',' + longitude +'?units=si';

    request({ url, json: true }, (error, {body,  }) => {
        if (error) {
            callback('Unable to connect to weather service!', undefined)
        } else if (body.error) {
            callback('Unable to find location', undefined)
        }

        callback(undefined, body.daily.data[0].summary + ' It is currently ' + body.daily.data[0].temperatureMax + ' Max degress & ' +body.daily.data[0].temperatureMin +' Min degress. There is a ' + body.daily.data[0].precipProbability
            + '% chance of rain. icon:  ' + body.daily.icon  );
    })
};

module.exports = forecast;
```

from app.js file

```
app.get('/weather', (req,res)=>{
    if (!req.query.address){
        return res.send({
            error:'You must provide an address'
        })
    }
    geocode(req.query.address,(error,{latitude,longitude,location  } ={})=>{
        if (error){
           return  res.send({error})
        }
        forecast(latitude,longitude,(error,forcastData,iconsky)=>{
            if (error){
                return  res.send({error})
            }
            res.send({
                forcast:forcastData,
                location,
                address: req.query.address,


            })
        })
    })
});
```

and this is geocode.js file

```
const request = require('request');

const geocode = (address, callback) => {
    const url = 'https://api.mapbox.com/geocoding/v5/mapbox.places/' + address +
        '.json?access_token=pk.eyJ1Ijoic29sb3JhbmdlciIsImEiOiJjanoxb2RwdGowbmF3M2JrbnA0OGI1Nzd2In0.ZLeKIz5F7OlG5GxVaKZj0g&limit=1';

    request({ url, json: true }, (error, {body}) => {
        if (error) {
            callback('Unable to connect to location services!', undefined)
        } else if (body.features.length === 0) {
            callback('Unable to find location. Try another search.', undefined)
        } else {
            callback(undefined, {
                latitude: body.features[0].center[0],
                longitude: body.features[0].center[1],
                location: body.features[0].place_name
            })
        }
    })
};

module.exports = geocode;
```

I want to access icons in api to res.send in app.js but I can't access it from there. How can I do it?

Comment: `Skyicon = body.daily.icon` what is `Skyicon`?

Comment: sorry its a little mistake i edited it

Comment: Now you just removed the parameter completly, you're not passing any value to `iconsky` parameter in the callback.

Answer (score 1):

Two things. One, adjust your callback from forecast.js, instead of

```
callback(undefined, body.daily.data[0].summary + ' It is currently ' + body.daily.data[0].temperatureMax + ' Max degress & ' +body.daily.data[0].temperatureMin +' Min degress. There is a ' + body.daily.data[0].precipProbability
        + '% chance of rain. icon:  ' + body.daily.icon  );
})
```

call back like this:

```
callback(undefined, body.daily.data[0].summary + ' It is currently ' + body.daily.data[0].temperatureMax + ' Max degress & ' +body.daily.data[0].temperatureMin +' Min degress. There is a ' + body.daily.data[0].precipProbability
        + '% chance of rain.', body.daily.icon  );
});
```

The difference is that I put icon as a third argument.

The second, you can now access it in app.js after the forecast call:

```
forecast(latitude,longitude,(error,forcastData,iconsky)=>{
    if (error){
        return  res.send({error})
    }
    res.send({
        forcast:forcastData,
        location,
        address: req.query.address,
        icon: iconsky,
    })
})
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if there is some documentation to their API that has the "right" way, but you can always leverage the icons the same way they are. Their apex domain (darksky.net) has an `images/weather-icons` folder containing the actual file.

```
 //darksky.net/images/weather-icons/{icon-name.ext}
```

Your question is tagged with Node, so you may need need to download the file? or just create an image tag with the above source. I'm not sure of your intentions.

Comment: i know this. but how can i acces to body.daily.icon from forecast.js to app.js?
 if i want to use this url i should acces to body.daily.icon from app.js file